# Check if device has hardware volume controls?

Tags: android

Some devices like Kindle fire do not have hardware buttons for volume, so I was going to add some on screen controls, but I don't want to have them there if they are not necessary.

I can't find any info on this, I've looked in `PackageManager` features, plus [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html).

Is it true maybe that all devices have hardware volume controls with exception of kindle fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android.view.KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
```